# how to set pp::URLLoader to cache DNS forever

Tags: dns, google-nativeclient

using Chrome's Native Client pp::URLLoader, is it possible to set the loader to cache the DNS forever, like curllib's CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT option (setting to -1 to cache the DNS record for ever.)   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT.html

Confirming 'No' is also very helpful!

Thank you

Comment: As a network engineer, I would urge you not to bypass TTLs for caching. If you want to override the DNS response, either use a static DNS entry that you can control or override it locally with something like a hosts entry.

Comment: Thank you. But we have to appreciate the irrational requests from arrogant, thinking-they-know-everything-and-not-listening customer.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to control this. [Here is the list of properties](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_stable/c/group___enums#ga41975630f0a4c49e47d4a21754f8402d) that can be set on a URLRequest.

As I understand it, DNS caching for URLLoader requests is controlled entirely by the Chrome network stack. You can take a look at chrome://net-internals/#dns to see whether Chrome is caching the request.

Comment: Thank you. I am taking this as an answer, as long as there is no further objection. :-)